# Splitting Column of a data.table

Tags: r, data.table, reshape, reshape2

Wonder how to split column of a data.table.

Can split column of a `data.frame` easily with the following code:

```
df <- data.frame(Test=c("A - B", "C - D"))
df
     Test
1 A - B
2 C - D
library(reshape2)
reshape2:::colsplit(string = df[,1], pattern = " ", names = c("Var1", "Space", "Var2"))

  Var1 Space Var2
1    A     -    B
2    C     -    D
```

But my attempt of splitting column of a `data.table` fails

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(Test=c("A - B", "C - D"))
dt
    Test
1: A - B
2: C - D
reshape2:::colsplit(string = dt[,1, with=FALSE], pattern = " ", names = c("Var1", "Space", "Var2"))
Error: String must be an atomic vector
```

Comment: Try `string = dt[[1]]`

Comment: Thanks @Arun for your help. Could you change your comment to answer and explain the logic behind `[[1]]`. Thanks

Comment: @MYaseen208, just use `class` in order to understand it. In short, when you do `df[,1]` it becomes a vector (no longer a `data.frame`), however when you do `dt[,1, with=FALSE]`, it is still a `data.table`. The error of `colsplit` clearly states that you have to give it an atomic vector, thus in order to achieve this, you do `dt[[1]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you're specifically asking for something with `colsplit`, but I would suggest looking at some of the other alternatives out there, for example my `cSplit` function.

The `cSplit` approach would be as follows:

```
setnames(cSplit(dt, "Test",  " "), c("Var1", "Space", "Var2"))[]
#    Var1 Space Var2
# 1:    A     -    B
# 2:    C     -    D
```

The `[]` at the end is to print the result, but you can also just store the result as a new `data.table` instead.

---

How does it compare in terms of efficiency?

```
fun1 <- function() {
  reshape2:::colsplit(string = dt[[1]], pattern = " ", 
                      names = c("Var1", "Space", "Var2"))
} 
fun2 <- function() {
  setnames(cSplit(dt, "Test",  " "), 
           c("Var1", "Space", "Var2"))[]
}

dt <- rbindlist(replicate(5000, dt, FALSE))
dim(dt)
# [1] 10000     1

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(fun1(), fun2(), times = 10)
# Unit: milliseconds
#    expr        min         lq     median         uq        max neval
#  fun1() 2025.84703 2093.39687 2195.75822 2390.30666 2492.65946    10
#  fun2()   34.08966   36.01145   43.28036   47.45962   57.57615    10
```

---

Why didn't your `colsplit` approach work as you expected?

`dt[,1]` is more like `df[,1, drop = FALSE]` (try it--you'll get the same error that you got with your "data.table" attempt).

You will need either of the following:

```
> dt[[1]]
[1] "A - B" "C - D"
> dt$Test
[1] "A - B" "C - D"
```

Which is similar to what you get with:

```
> df[, 1]
[1] A - B C - D
Levels: A - B C - D
```